# How to set the background image on slider in untiy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

*How can I set the background image on slider..?*
*or can i change attach material to slider and can change back it on click..??*

If the value of `slider variable ==1` can set image 1,
 and if value of `slider variable==2` can set image 2 on slider..is it possible,..??

```
void OnGUI(){
        GUI.skin=myskin;
        GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
        GUILayout.Box ("sliderValue : " +  Mathf.RoundToInt(sliderValue));

        sliderValue = GUILayout.HorizontalSlider(sliderValue ,1.0f, maxSliderValue);
        if (sliderValue == 1) {


                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just change background and thumb style.

```
float sliderValue;
float maxSliderValue = 2.0f;
public GUIStyle backgroundStyle;
public GUIStyle thumbStyle;
public Texture2D tex, tex2, thumbTex;

void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
    GUILayout.Box ("sliderValue : " +  Mathf.RoundToInt(sliderValue));

    thumbStyle.normal.background = thumbTex;
    thumbStyle.fixedWidth = 20;
    thumbStyle.fixedHeight = 20;

    if (Mathf.RoundToInt(sliderValue) == 1)
        backgroundStyle.normal.background = tex;
    else
        backgroundStyle.normal.background = tex2;

    sliderValue = GUILayout.HorizontalSlider(sliderValue ,1.0f, maxSliderValue, backgroundStyle, thumbStyle);
}
```